# Get a specific data from ResultSet with rs.next()

Tags: jsp, servlets, resultset

I am trying to get a `<td>` data which click the button and fetch it to the servlet. I've tried to add a hidden input which used to store the data from ResultSet but I only can get the very first row of the data.

If there are any other better method to do it, please do tell me instead, thank you.

```
<form action="Order_view" method="post">


    <%
        try {
         //Connection Code

    %>
       <table border=1 align=center style="text-align: center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Package ID</th>
                <th>Type</th>
            </tr>

            <%while (rs.next()) {
            %>

            <tr>

                <td><%out.print(rs.getString(1));%></td>
                <td><%out.print(rs.getString(2));%></td>  

                <td><button name="btnView">View</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" />
            </tr>

        <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <%} catch (SQLException e) {
        out.print(e.getMessage());%><br><%
        }
    %>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `<form>` to do that,also yes you will be getting first row only, to overcome that you can do like below :

```
 <%
        try {
         //Connection Code

    %>
       <table border=1 align=center style="text-align: center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Package ID</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

            <%while (rs.next()) {
            %>

            <tr>
                <td><%out.print(rs.getString(1));%></td>
                <td><%out.print(rs.getString(2));%></td>
        <!--here we are passing "id" of that particular row in <a href>--> 
                <td><a href="Yourservleturl?id=<%=resultset.getString(1) %> "><input type="button" value="View"></a></td>
               </tr>
        <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <%} catch (SQLException e) {
        out.print(e.getMessage());%><br><%
        }
    %>
```

And then in your `servlet` get that id by using `request.getParameter("id");` in your `doGet` method for futher processing.